Can every spanning tree result from a depth-first search?
A graph can have multiple spanning trees and the spanning tree resulting from a depth-first search depends on the order in which edges are processed. Can every possible spanning tree of a given graph be produced from that graph if the edge processing order is determined appropriately?

Consider a complete graph $K_n$. Then a depth-first search can only create a linear-path spanning tree, no matter what the edges processing order is.

Another easy example can be a cycle $C_n$.

@codeR all spanning trees of a cycle $C_n$ can be obtained using DFS if you can choose edge ordering AND starting vertex.

Yes, indeed, if you change the start vertex. But the question only asks about selecting edges in different order once you start.
